# when to use master layout and partial view MVC c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

As I see master layout and partial view has same functionally. for example I have one master layout page which has `<html> <head> <body>` elements. all pages are inherited from it, then I have 10 pages for example they all have same navigation bar, what should i do should i create master page which inherits from first master page and all these 10 page inherit from second master page, or should i create partial view and render it in all 10 pages.

Comment: Try reading this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts

Answer (score 0):

They have different intended uses.

Master views can be thought of like master "templates" or layouts, where all pages in a certain area or module will use that as a base layout. They often have RenderSection and RenderBody helper tags.

Partial views are when you usually fragments of tags and markup that you use frequently, so you factor them into a partial view to reuse them.

A typical site might have one or two master pages (maybe one page for public facing, unauthenticated, and a second page for internal, authenticated pages). Master pages will have sections like header, body, footer. You often have branding on them, as well as nav bars and even news sections, blog posts, or whatever else you normally have in surrounding content.

Based on your description, sounds like you might want two different master pages, each for a group of like views.

Partial views would often be something like a data grid, or a footer, or a chart, or anything reusable.

Answer (score 0):

"Master" is a term from Web Forms. Avoid using it in the context of MVC. In MVC you have layouts, views, and partial views. In reality, these are all just "views". The key distinction of a layout is merely that it's *used as a layout*, while a view uses a layout. A partial view is really just a view that doesn't use a layout.

As far as inheritance goes, since a layout is just a view, it can both be a layout *and* use a layout. That's your extension point. For example:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

**_SubLayout.cshtml**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<div class="content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

**SomeView.cshtml**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SubLayout.cshtml"; }

<p>Foo</p>
```

The resulting HTML for `SomeView.cshtml` once rendered would be:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Foo</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```